# What exegetical conclusion can be drawn about the order of the last days Second Coming harvest (Matthew 13:30, 36-43)?

Tags: matthew, eschatology, parables

Does this parable of Jesus about the **Tares** provide sufficient information in order to make conclusions about the order of dealings in the Second Coming of Christ.  That is, what do the tares being taken out **first**, before the righteous saints are dealt with, have to say about the End Time? Does it provide enough information to contribute to a timeline and help make conclusions about what the rest of the Bible says about the order of events in the End? ( Gk. *synteleia tou aionos*)

> Allow both to grow up together (good wheat and tares) until the harvest, and in the time of the harvest I will say to the reapers, "**First** gather up the tares and bind them in bundles to burn them up; but gather the wheat to my barn." (Matthew 13:30)

> ...the field is the world; and as for the good sees, these are the sons of the Kingdom; and the tare are the sons of the evil one; and the enemy who sowed them is the devil, and the harvest is the End of the Age; and the reapers are angels.
>  So just as the tares are gathered up and burned with fire, so shall it be at the end of the Age. The Son of Man will send forth His angels, and they will gather out of His kingdom all stumbling blocks, and those who commit lawlessness, and will throw them into the fiery furnace; in that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.
> **Then** the righteous will shine forth as the sun in the Kingdom of their Father. He who who has ears, let him hear. (Matthew 13:38-43)

Comment: This is a good question, and I would agree with you. I've found the parables of Jesus to be multi-layered and dangerously context sensitive! As a result, I've drawn a tentative conclusion for two rapture events: one for the Bride of Christ *before* the Great Tribulation, and a second one for the truly evil people *at the end of the age* just before the start of the Millennium.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not good hermeneutics to look at the rest of the Bible through the lens of one particular parable. Various eschatological views may be drawn from various passages. Even comparing the parable of the Wheat and the Tares with the explanation given in Mt. 13:36 shows this.

The parable itself emphasizes the present. It teaches the church to be patient and allow sinners and saints to coexist. The explanation later in the chapter shifts to the future and says nothing about how the church is to treat sinners in this world.

But if we turn the  Revelation 14 we find a different scenario. The judgment here is based on whether people have accepted the "mark of the Beast."  It is no longer a matter of saints and sinners growing up together in the church, but of a momentous worldwide choice during a time of tribulation. So the third angel declares:

> Anyone who worships the beast or its image, or accepts its mark on
> forehead or hand, 10 will also drink the wine of God’s fury poured
> full strength into the cup of his wrath, and will be tormented in
> burning sulfur before the holy angels and before the Lamb.

Note also that the metaphor (if it is indeed a metaphor) has shifted from weeds burning in a furnace to human beings tormented with burning sulfur. Shortly after this, an angel carries out the harvest. But there is a difference here too, for the angel does this himself, without the aid of other angels as in the Gospel of Matthew:

> Another angel came out of the temple, crying out in a loud voice to
> the one sitting on the cloud, “Use your sickle and reap the harvest,
> for the time to reap has come, because the earth’s harvest is fully
> ripe.” 16 So the one who was sitting on the cloud swung his sickle
> over the earth, and the earth was harvested.

Then, in chapter 20 we find that, after 1000 years, the evil people have not been consumed in the fire. They are released from their sulfurous torment, and we are told that there is to be a second judgement. It is based on neither on a harvest of souls that have grown up together nor on whether people have accepted the mark of the Beast. Instead:

> 5 Anyone whose name was not found written in the book of life was
> thrown into the pool of fire.

**Conclusion**: the above examples represent just a few of the problems in understanding how Mt. 13 relates to the Book of Revelation, let alone the many other eschatological passages in the Bible. In one passage, Jesus says he will return and the angels will gather the elect within one generation of his own lifetime (Matthew 24:34).  In another, (Mt. 25) he says that he himself will separate the "sheep" from the "goats" and judge them based on how they treated others, then send the wicked ones to the fire prepared by the angels - who have no role in the gathering or windowing. It may be possible to harmonize the many various accounts, but none of them is sufficient to draw a definite conclusion other than that there will be a final judgment with rewards and punishments. Rather than beginning with Mt. 13 and viewing the others based on its teaching, a wise exegete might want to start with the disclaimer that Jesus himself admitted and keep it in mind:

Mark 13:32

> But of that day or hour, no one knows, neither the angels in heaven,
> nor the Son, but only the Father.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 13:30 is a metaphor emphasizes the distinction between sinners and the righteous, rather than focusing on the specific order of separation. Jesus often used parables drawn from daily experiences to connect with His contemporary audience, ensuring accessibility.

Consider the context of Revelation 14:14-20, the angel responsible for harvesting the righteous is mentioned before the one gathering the sinners. However, this sequence does not necessarily imply that the righteous are taken before the sinners.

What holds greater significance is the understanding that at the Second Coming of Christ, the final judgement will definitively separate the sinners from the righteous. This pivotal event is likely to occur simultaneously, emphasizing the ultimate justice and accountability.